# (Linear?) Optimization problem

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I’m trying to solve this problem, but being very new to this kind of thing, I do not know how to proceed. Grateful for any help or guidance you are able to provide.

Find all $S_i$, such that:

It minimizes $\sum_{i=1}^n|A_i-T_i|$ where $A_i = \frac{S_i}{S_1 + S_2 + ... + S_n}$, and $T_i$ are other constants provided to you

Given:

- $\sum_{i=1}^nS_iP_i < K$
- $P_i$ and $K$ are all floating point constants provided to you.
- All $S_i$ must be integers $\geq 0$.
- If there are multiple solutions, pick the one that minimizes $K - \sum_{i=1}^nS_iP_i$.

I’d appreciate being able to solve this problem myself. However, ways to solve it using python libraries or things like Wolfram Alpha are good too.

Comment: I wrote the equations in latex.  Please check if I have done a correct interpretation, or if I have accidentally changed your problem.  I also removed the $K_p$ constant from multiplying the sum to be minimized, since (assuming $K_p>0$) that would not change the minimization.  However, I do not know why there would be two different objective functions to minimize.  Usually an optimization seeks to minimize a single objective function subject to constraints.  Also, this is certainly not a linear optimization problem.

Comment: @Michael is correct. There will be one solution ${S^*_i}$ which will minimize $|\sum_{i}S_iP_i-K|$, and a different ${S^{**}_i}$  which will minimize  $|\sum_{i}A_iP-T_i|$. It is possible that your constants are fortuitously such that the two solutions are the same or very similar, but in the general case, tat wouldn;t be true So, you need to tradeoff. The general way to do it is to compose a hybrid objective function $|\sum_{i}S_iP_i-K|+\lambda  |\sum_{i}A_iP-T_i|$. Where $\lambda$ is a parameter you decide on the relative weights of the two objective functions.

Comment: If you sort out what you want your objective function to be, It can be modeled as a linear programming problem.

Comment: Thank you both, Michael and @skr. I understand now why having the two objective functions is weird. I’ve re-written the problem with a local minimizer in the case there are multiple solutions. Is the new formulation solvable?

Comment: I would start from setting $\sum S_i=\mu$ and considering two minimizations: inner for a fixed $\mu$ and outer over $\mu\ge 0$. The inner minimization can be written as LP if we write it as $\min t$ subject to $\sum(\pm(S_i/\mu-T_i))\le t$, $P^TS\le K$, $S\ge 0$.